# LookUp Transformation Dynamic SQL Query in ssis 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ssis, lookup

I have been trying to add a dynamic query into LookUp Transformation editor(writing a query instead of a table for lookup) in SSIS 2012 and I am unable to do. I Have referenced many articles([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222262/ssis-lookup-transformation-advanced-editormodify-the-sql-statement) and [this](https://suneethasdiary.wordpress.com/2011/12/28/creating-a-dynamic-query-in-lookup-transformation-in-ssis/)) and all have been saying to use SQLCommand in property and make it as expression. But I am unable to get that. Is there some thing missing? below is a screen shot where instead of expression editor I am getting String Value editor.

Since I don't have 10 reputation I am unable to post the Screen shot.

Comment: Could you help me understand why you think you need a dynamic query?

Comment: I was doing a lookup from a input with lookup Transformation to achieve something like this. select * from table where col1 = variableName(this varies with users choice, which is why I require Dynamic Query) and then take these results to lookup with my input results so that I can filter out records that are matching my lookup criteria and also report ones that are not matching.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Cache as source of your lookup? In that way you could use a dynamic sql statement in a DFT Source and use Cache Transform as your destination, then use that cache connection as source of your lookup.

Answer (score 0):

The explanation from the answer you linked too was a bit confusing to me so maybe you had the same problem. What you have to do is this:

In your `Control Flow` select the Data Flow Task. In the Properties of the Data Flow Task you will see the property Expressions. Press the ellipsis and you should be able to configure the expression for the SQLCommand.

[image]

Comment: Hey JodyT, Thanks for the reply. I needed the LookUp transformation to perform records that match a criteria and also capture ones that does not match criteria. Please check my comment to billinkc.

Answer (score 0):

In the Lookup Properties dialog box, make sure you have not selected "Full Cache" mode.  Go to the Advanced screen, and check "Modify the SQL Statement".   Here you can type in a SQL Statement with ? as parameter placeholders and click "Parameters..." to assign their values to input columns.   Looks like you can't use variables, but you could populate an extra column in your dataflow source to populate the lookup parameter when it gets there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I did try that option but I was getting the parameters cannot be extracted from the sql statement. The provider might not help parse parameter information from statement error. I did check my OLEDB connection and have no issues with that.

Comment: What is the query that you are trying to parameterize in the lookup?   SSIS has a problem parameterizing certain queries (subselects, cte, etc).   Maybe it can be re-written in a simpler form.

Comment: select Col1, Col2, Col3 from table where Dept = 'myparametershouldbehere' is my Connection manager query to the Lookup 

and the input to the Look up has Col1 and Col2 on which its making the look up. So the SQL statement would look something like this 

Select * from (select Col1, Col2,Col3 from table where Dept = 'fornowhardcodedValue') reftable where reftable.Col1 = ? amd reftable.Col2 = ?

Comment: Yeah the fact that you're selecting from a derived table is causing the problem with the parameters.   If you can't simplify your query, you're going to have to Lookup on the whole table without parameters.   Why can't you do SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM table WHERE Dept=?